# Kali live usb "Module w0 not found in directory" Broadcom 4360

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, macintosh, broadcom, persistence

I am on Kali Linux.

I'm trying to install the Broadcom BMD4360 drivers in my MacbookPro i7, in live USB mode, but I got some errors.

Is there any way to fix it without reinstall all over again?

So, first I installed the headers:

```
 apt-get update

 apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

After I removed the possible conflicts

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
```

And got this:

```
root@kali:/etc/apt# modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-686-pae
```

So I tried to install in a different way and I had:

```
root@kali:/var/lib# apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  broadcom-sta-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1185 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package broadcom-sta-dkms.
(Reading database ... 335533 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-4) ...
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-4) ...
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Building for 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae
Module build for kernel 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

and after I got a new errors in modprobe:

```
root@kali:/var/lib# modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:977 command_do() Error running install command for wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted
```

My `uname -a` is

```
root@kali:/lib/modules# uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) i686 GNU/Linux
```

The modules available are listed:

```
root@kali:/lib/modules# ls
4.6.0-kali1-686-pae  4.8.0-kali1-686  4.8.0-kali1-686-pae  4.8.0-kali1-rt-686-pae
```

and `/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/source/dkms.conf` follows

```
root@kali:/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/source# cat dkms.conf
PACKAGE_NAME="broadcom-sta"
PACKAGE_VERSION="6.30.223.271"
MAKE[0]="make KVER=$kernelver"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="wl"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
REMAKE_INITRD="YES
```

Is there any way to fix it without reinstall all over again?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue; I followed every tutorial out there but couldn't get it to work :(

What *did* work was to download and install the packages manually.

First run

```
uname -r
```

to get your OS kernel version (for the purpose of this example `4.6.0-kali1-amd64`).

Then download either in GUI the packages you need:

- [linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb)
- [linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb)
- [linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb)
- [linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb)

, or in CLI download them directly in terminal:

```
wget --continue http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
wget --continue http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
wget --continue http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
wget --continue http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
```

To install them, run:

```
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
```

Then download [bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/226723001/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb) either in GUI, or in CLI download it directly in terminal:

```
wget --continue http://launchpadlibrarian.net/226723001/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

To install it, run:

```
sudo dpkg --install bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

And finish with there `modprobe` commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe -v wl
```

And voila, it should be working!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help @pmalbu ! So, I followed your steps, but I had some errors when I ran `sudo dpkg --install linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb` and `sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb` commands... Basically the errors are:  

`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86:
 linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86 depends on gcc-5;` 

Did I something wrong? :(

Comment: Hi @Murchilla.  Hmm no I am sure you did it correctly, but it appears that there are other unmet dependencies.  I am not an expert in this area unfortunately, however Google may be able to help you out!

Answer (score 1):

I found dependencies missing and this are all the packages I had to install.

Now works fine.

```
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb   
linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb             
linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common-rt_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-all-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb  
linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-rt-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb      
linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb
```

PS: This one helped a lot:  `apt --fix-broken install`